# struggling with programmatically adding user controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have the same problem as in the question [Programmatically added User Control does not create its child controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577353/programmatically-added-user-control-does-not-create-its-child-controls).

After reading the question and answer I changed my code which now looks like this:

```
foreach (ITask task in tasks)
{
    TaskListItem taskListItem = LoadControl(
        typeof(TaskListItem),
        new object[] {task}
    ) as TaskListItem;

    taskListItem.TaskCompleteChanged += taskListItem_TaskCompleteChanged;                        

    taskListItemHolder.Controls.Add(taskListItem);
}
```

However, I'm still getting a user control whose child controls haven't been instantiated.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use this instead:

```
foreach (ITask task in tasks)
{
  TaskListItem taskListItem = LoadControl("~/TaskListItem.ascx") as TaskListItem;

  taskListItem.Task = task;
  taskListItem.TaskCompleteChanged +=
      taskListItem_TaskCompleteChanged;                        

  taskListItemHolder.Controls.Add(taskListItem);
}
```

This is because TaskListItem is not the type of the real control, but the type of the control's code-behind class. Check [this page in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewtd66a0.aspx) (at the bottom, in the community content).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're adding the controls in the CreateChildControls method (you can override it), also, give the control an ID (which needs to be the same everytime you add it).